# Java 2d tile map collision, player character can't move

Tags: java, game-physics

I am making a 2d game that uses tiles right now. I am at the part of making a collision system so the character does not clip his way though the maze. however after making the system the player is just stuck in spot with the moving walking animations playing. for the collision I made a class that looks at all the 2d array that holds my game map and draws rectangles where collisions need to happen. I then store the rectangles in an array list and check using the .intersects function. this is the code :
Collision.java

```
public class Collision {

    GamePanel p;
    Rectangle playerRect;
    ArrayList<Rectangle> collisionMap; // Create an ArrayList object

    public Collision (GamePanel p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
    public boolean checkCollision() {
        playerRect = new Rectangle(p.player.worldX,p.player.worldY,p.TILE_SIZE,p.TILE_SIZE); 
        collisionMap = new ArrayList<Rectangle>(); // initialize the array list
        Rectangle tileRect;
        for (int row = 0; row < 50; row ++) { // rows
            for (int colum = 0; colum < 50; colum++) { // colum
                if (p.tiles.gameMap[row][colum] == 0) { 
                    tileRect = new Rectangle(row * p.TILE_SIZE,colum * p.TILE_SIZE,p.TILE_SIZE,p.TILE_SIZE);
                    collisionMap.add(tileRect);
                }
            }
        }
        for (Rectangle collision : collisionMap) {
            if (collision.intersects(playerRect));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

player.java
collision part

```
public void updatePlayerCollision() {
        collisionOn = false; // set collisionOn to false at start
        collisionOn = gamePanel.cChecker.checkCollision(); // look if there is any collision that has happen
        if (collisionOn == true) {

        }
        
        if (collisionOn == false) { // if collision didn't happen player moves
            switch (direction) {
                case "up":
                    worldY -= speed;
                    break;
                case "down":
                    worldY += speed;
                    break;
                case "left":
                    worldX -= speed;
                    break;
                case "right":
                    worldX += speed;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried reversing the movement direction if a collision is detected, but that just seems to make the player travel in reverse constantly with collisions not working

Comment: After you notice that your code doesn't perform the way you anticipated, you should start debugging. Have you tried to debug your code? If not, why not? If so, what did you discover?